# android eclipse java logcat runtime errors

Tags: android, eclipse

```
04-21 02:27:40.341: E/vold(27): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)

04-21 02:27:40.341: E/vold(27): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)

04-21 02:27:40.341: E/vold(27): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)

04-21 02:27:40.341: E/vold(27): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)

04-21 02:27:49.111: E/BatteryService(52): usbOnlinePath not found

04-21 02:27:49.111: E/BatteryService(52): batteryVoltagePath not found

04-21 02:27:49.111: E/BatteryService(52): batteryTemperaturePath not found

04-21 02:27:49.111: E/SurfaceFlinger(52): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake

04-21 02:27:52.211: E/EventHub(52): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter

04-21 02:27:52.211: E/EventHub(52): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter

04-21 02:27:53.231: E/System(52): Failure starting core service

04-21 02:27:53.231: E/System(52): java.lang.SecurityException

04-21 02:27:53.231: E/System(52):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)

04-21 02:27:53.231: E/System(52):   at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)

04-21 02:27:53.231: E/System(52):   at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)

04-21 02:27:53.231: E/System(52):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:176)

04-21 02:27:53.251: E/AndroidRuntime(52): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service

04-21 02:28:01.915: E/ActivityThread(102): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin

04-21 02:28:03.255: E/ActivityThread(102): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin

04-21 02:28:03.325: E/ActivityThread(102): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin

04-21 02:28:05.265: E/MediaPlayerService(31): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/notification_sound

04-21 02:28:05.295: E/MediaPlayer(52): Unable to to create media player

04-21 02:28:13.005: E/AndroidRuntime(131): ERROR: thread attach failed

04-21 02:28:14.785: E/AndroidRuntime(210): ERROR: thread attach failed

04-21 02:28:14.975: E/jdwp(222): Failed sending req to debugger: Broken pipe (-1 of 27)

04-21 02:28:14.975: E/jdwp(222): Failed sending req to debugger: Broken pipe (-1 of 27)

04-21 02:28:14.975: E/jdwp(222): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
```

Comment: how about some information about the context in which this error occurs? Some code you execute in TestsDemo.java line 40... give us something to help you!

Comment: Your error appears in the onCreate function (line 40). Could you post the onCreate method and any other relevant information?

Comment: `UnsatisfiedLinkError`: looks like you did not include a native library required by your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your native function signature. You should decare it with JNIEXPORT and JNICALL.

Use the [javah](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html) tool for generating header and source files.

Here is example: [JNI Example](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html)

And next time try to find some related answers like [java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813336/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror) before asking another question.

Comment: 'm using windows where s tis sys/ coming from ?

Comment: my project ll complete if i port my game to android . help needed guys

Comment: Please don't rewrite the question! You should rather ask new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253879/android-eclipse-java-logcat-runtime-linker-errors#comment13181572_10253879 here