# ndk-build not compiling the lib.so files

Tags: android, android-ndk

im building native code for android from command line via `cd <project> ndk-build` but when i run it it outputs `nothing can be done for 'all'` im using code from HelloJni sample, and if i import the the sample and compile it everything works fine.

activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.i("DEBUG", stringFromJNI());
        setContentView(new MySurfaceView(this));
    }

    public native String stringFromJNI();

    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("nativemain");
    }
}
```

nativemain.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

jstring Java_com_ndktest2_MainActivity_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !");
}
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := nativemain
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := nativemain.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := armeabi
```

Thank you so much for you guys and gals help!!

UPDATE 1: i refreshed the project and ran ndk-build again and work, but i received a UnsatisfiedLinkError exception on run time. Im using BlueStack as my emulator.

[image]

Comment: Dumb questions (please, be patient): 1) do you have the latest version of the NDK? 2) My NDK projects don't have an "Application.mk" (and neither the hello-jni project in my android-ndk package does...): what happens with ndk-build if you remove it?

Comment: Thanks Rick77 i gues i should of removed it after successfull build with ndk-build, do you mind posting an this as an answer

Comment: Very kind of you, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the "Application.mk" as it's not required for single-ndk-module applications (and the hello-jni doesn't have one)

Answer (score 2):

Try putting a

```
JNIEXPORT
```

in front of your

```
Java_com_ndktest2_MainActivity_stringFromJNI
```

declaration.

Also the following SO questions might be related to your problem:

[Android-NDK “java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704920/android-ndk-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror?rq=1)

[java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813336/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror)

Hope this helps